# 配列から重複のないグループに分ける方法

Tags: ruby

配列から、3つずつ重複なしでグループわけした値を作りたいのですが、
何をどうして処理したらいいのかわかりません。

アドバイスを頂けませんか。

以下のような感じです。

```
items = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "F", "F", "F", "G", "H", "I"]

hoge(items)
# => [
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["A", "B", "F"],
  ["A", "F", "G"],
  ["F", "H", "I"]
]
```

組み合わせや順番はこの通りでなくても大丈夫です。

ruby,php,javascriptのいずれかで解説してくださると嬉しいですが、他の言語でも大丈夫です。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: items の要素は11個ですが、結果の要素が12個ありますが、間違いでしょうか。

Comment: すみません、間違っていました。修正しました。

Comment: @snxpwf ruby php javascriptとありますが、言語により実装のしやすさも変わると思います。考え方を知りたいだけなのか、それとも楽な実装を知りたいだけなのかドチラでしょうか？

Comment: `[ABF, ACF, AFG, BHI]`のようなグループ分けも考えられますが、それは気にしないという意味ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

別解として `inject` を使う方法を。

```
items = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "F", "F", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
items.inject([]){|arr, i|
  f = arr.find{|x| !x.include?(i) && x.length < 3}
  f.nil? ? arr << [i] : f << i
  arr
}
=> [["A", "B", "C"], ["A", "B", "F"], ["A", "F", "G"], ["F", "H", "I"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

ベタですが、一応こんな感じでできました。

```
items = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "F", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
results = []
while item = items.shift
  catch :next do
    results.each do |rec|
      if rec.size < 3 && !rec.include?(item)
        rec.push item
        throw :next
      end
    end
    results.push [item]
  end
end
p results
```

Answer (score -1):

combination をつかうと、

```
items = ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "F", "F", "G", "H", "I"];
items.uniq.combination(3).each do |arr| print arr, "\n"; end
```

です。